# What is the verb that describes when a feeling takes you over?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Sometimes a feeling becomes so deep and so huge that it kinda takes you with it. It's like the feeling becomes a huge body of water that comes over you from every direction and you somehow drown in it like all you see and feel is that feeling and the rest of the world disappears. like it submerges you. Is there any specific word for it?
That could be used in the following context:

> That deep feeling comes all at once and it `takes over you`.

P.S. Please consider adding a few examples of your suggestions.

Comment: For a single word request, a sample sentence is necessary to indicate how you would use the word supplied.

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes feel '**overwhelmed**'.

> to overpower in thought or feeling overwhelmed with grief overwhelmed by terror A sense of inadequacy overwhelmed me. overwhelmed with guilt

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overwhelm)

> '**Overwhelmed**’ veteran, 87, in tears after winning £18m jackpot with wife

[inews 21 Feb 2018](https://inews.co.uk/news/lottery-win-couple-scooped-18-million-say-played-daughters/)

> 1961   I. Murdoch Severed Head xii. 110   A protective love for Antonia **overwhelmed** me, a desire to carry her away and hide her.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/135363?rskey=XOj62l&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

Answer (score 2):

I've commonly heard *sweep* used in a similar manner.  I was *swept away* with emotion.

Answer (score 0):

The verb **transport** is sometimes used in this sense.  The OED definition is

> To ‘carry away’ with the strength of some emotion; to cause to be beside oneself, to put into an ecstasy, to enrapture.

An example from Dickens's *Barnaby Rudge*:

> Transported with the thought that rescue had at length arrived, Emma and Dolly shrieked aloud for help.

And, more contemporarily, here's [Ron Howard talking about seeing *Star Wars* in 1977:](http://variety.com/2017/film/news/ron-howard-star-wars-han-solo-cannes-1202476899/)

> When “Star Wars” came out, on opening day Howard said he and his wife, Cheryl, went to go see it — and they stood in line for two hours to get in. **“I was so moved by the movie,” he said. “I was transported by the movie...  We literally left almost speechless.”** They decided to see it again, and waited another 90 minutes in line.